# Existence of abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have two questions:

1) How many non abelian groups of order 17 are there?

2) Exists an abelian group of order 6102?

to 1) i don´t have an explaination, to 2) i would say $\Bbb Z/6102\Bbb Z$ is such a group.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use Lagrange Theorem to prove that there must be an element of order $17$ in any group of order $17$, which makes it a cyclic group and therefore an abelian.

On the otherside you're right $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is always a cyclic and abelian group.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain the downvote?

Comment: @user326049 First of all I didn't downvote, so all of this is based on assumption. MSE tends not to be a homework solving forum and you problem looks like one. Also you barely show any effort or where you encounter a problem.